# A way to form a 'select' on MVars without polling

Tags: haskell, concurrency, transactional-memory

I have two MVars (well an MVar and a Chan).  I need to pull things out of the Chan and process them until the other MVar is not empty any more.  My ideal solution would be something like the UNIX `select` function where I pass in a list of (presumably empty) MVars and the thread blocks until one of them is full, then it returns the full MVar.  Try as I might I can think of no way of doing this beyond repeatedly polling each MVar with isEmptyMVar until I get false.  This seems inefficient.

A different thought was to use throwTo, but it interrupts what ever is happening in the thread and I need to complete processing a job out the the Chan in an atomic fashion.

A final thought as I'm typing is to create a new forkIO for each MVar which tries to read its MVar then fill a newly created MVar with its own instance.  The original thread can then block on that MVar.  Are Haskell threads cheap enough to go running that many?

Comment: I wouldn't even think twice about having 1k threads running. 10k I might start thinking about measuring the overhead. 100k, definitely.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Haskell threads are very cheap, so you could solve it that way, but it sounds like STM would be a better fit for your problem. With STM you can do

```
do var <- atomically (takeTMVar a `orElse` takeTMVar b)
   ... do stuff with var
```

Because of the behavior of `retry` and `orElse`, this code tries to get `a`, then if that fails, get `b`. If both fail, it blocks until either of them is updated and tries again.

You could even use this to make your own rudimentary version of `select`:

```
select :: [TMVar a] -> STM a
select = foldr1 orElse . map takeTMVar
```

Answer (score 14):

How about using STM versions, `TChan` and `TVar`, with the `retry` and `orElse` behavior?

Implementing select is one of STM's nice capabilities. From "Composable Memory Transactions":

> Beyond this, we also provide orElse,
>   which allows them to be composed as alternatives, so that
>   the second is run if the ﬁrst retries (Section 3.4). This ability allows threads to wait for many things at once, like the
>   Unix select system call – except that orElse composes well,
>   whereas select does not.

---

- [`orElse` in RWH.](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/software-transactional-memory.html#id686416)
- [The STM package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/stm/2.2.0.1/doc/html/Control-Monad-STM.html)
- [Papers on Haskell's STM](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/stm/index.htm)